# Subgroups of product groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

In general, I feel like the group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ of integers under addition contain subgroups of the form $a\mathbb{Z} \times b\mathbb{Z}$.

In particular, I am trying to find how many such subgroups contain the product group of the even integers. I tried defining the surjective homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \to \{(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)\}$ under multiplication. Intuitively, I would think that this would lead to $4$ such subgroups. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, of the form you gave. There’s a fifth subgroup that isn’t of that form.

Comment: "the product group of the even integers" What does this mean? Does it mean, a group isomorphic to $2{\bf Z}\times2{\bf Z}$?

Comment: [Goursat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) may be of interest to you.